# How can I remove the underscore in the name of a column for a foreign key?

Tags: codefluent

My model contains the entities Order and Orderline. The Orderline has a property of type Order:

```
<cf:project 
    persistencePropertyNameFormat="{1}"        
    persistenceTableIdentifierSeparatorChar=""
    persistenceRelationIdentifierSeparatorChar="" ...>  

    <cf:entity name="Orderline">
        <cf:property name="Id"/>
        <cf:property name="Order" typeName="{0}.Order" />
    </cf:entity>
```

`CodeFluent` has created a database containing a table named `Orderline` with a column named `Order_Id`.
How can I remove the underscore in the name of this column?
I tried to specify an empty string for the `persistenceTableIdentifierSeparatorChar` and `persistenceRelationIdentifierSeparatorChar` attributes, but that didn't help.

Comment: persistencePropertyNameFormat="{1}" is indeed the way to do it http://blog.codefluententities.com/2011/02/02/persistence-property-name-format/. You don't need the xxChar attributes. Are you sure you have regenerated the database or you're looking at the good tables? Also please make sure you don't have a custom naming convention.

Comment: By default the name of the column for the foreign key is Orderline_Order_Id. By using persistencePropertyNameFormat="{1}" the name of the column becomes Order_Id. However, I want OrderId. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add a `persistenceName="OrderId"` attribute on the Order property.

Comment: I just discovered the custom naming feature of CodeFluent (https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/NC_ImplementingACustomNamingConvention.html). How can I remove the underscores in the column names with this feature?

Comment: you should ask another question